# Giving codeception and alias

Tags: php, terminal, command-line-interface, alias, codeception

I am trying to create an alias for running codeception via terminal.

If I simply run:

php /users/craig/vendor/codeception/codeception/codecept

that works.

But if in my bash_profile I create an alias:

```
alias gcc=“php /users/craig/vendor/codeception/codeception/codecept”
```

and run it I receive:

```
-bash: “php: command not found
```

How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the strange looking `“` and change your line to

```
alias gcc="php /users/craig/vendor/codeception/codeception/codecept"
```

Answer (score 1):

***FYI*** you can globally install codeception, and can call `codecept` anywhere from your system.

1. `sudo wget http://codeception.com/codecept.phar -O /usr/local/bin/codecept`
2. `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/codecept`